# Can you specify a separate trap in a subshell created with ()?

Tags: bash, shell, process, signals

I'm writing a script that starts a subshell to go off and do some work.  In a special case, the script needs to tell the subshell to cleanly stop what it's doing and exit early.  However, my psuedo-code below doesn't seem to be working.  Am I trying the impossible?  Is it possible to define a separate trap for signals in a subshell?

```
#!/bin/bash

function myExitFunction { ... }
trap myExitFunction SIGTERM

while [ 1 ] ; do
    waitForSpecialCondition

    kill -0 $SUBSHELL_PID   # check if subshell is running
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then  # and kill it if it is
        kill $SUBSHELL_PID
    fi

    (
    someProcess
    MYOWNCHILD=$!           # save someProcess's pid to kill later if I need to
    trap "kill $MYOWNCHILD" SIGTERM
    ... # do stuff
    ) &
    SUBSHELL_PID=$!

done
```

Comment: General note: signal handling is a little wonky in shells other than ksh. Beware that `( … ) &` might create a subprocess of a subprocess; try `{ … } &` instead. Other than that, the principle looks sane. For better answers, post code that we can run and try to fix (i.e. no `...` or undefined `waitForSpecialCondition`).

Comment: Thanks Gilles.  So it is even valid for a sub shell to have it's own signal trap?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. You can change the traps at any point, including when in a subshell. As usual what you do in the subshell doesn't change the state of the parent. Then the difficulty is mainly to bring the signals to the right process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was not what I really thought it was.  Below is a script that behaves like the psuedo-code above.  It functions exactly as I expected (although a little contrived in order to be simple), and is a good example of having separate signal traps for a parent and child shell process.

This trap functionality can be demonstrated by just running the script, and exiting by a ctrl-c.

```
#!/bin/bash

function endEarly {
echo "Terminating early"
if [ ! -z $SUBSHELL_PID ] ; then
    echo "Killing subshell with pid $SUBSHELL_PID"
    kill $SUBSHELL_PID
fi
exit
}

trap endEarly SIGTERM SIGINT

echo "Give me some input"
while [ 1 ] ; do
    read INPUT

    # kill the subshell if it exists and is running
    if [ ! -z $SUBSHELL_PID ] ; then
        kill -0 $SUBSHELL_PID
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            kill $SUBSHELL_PID
        fi
    fi

    echo "Now I'll repeat your input.  Feel free to change it"
    echo "at any time by typing it again and hitting <Enter>"
    {
        (
            while [ 1 ] ; do
                echo "$INPUT"
                sleep 5
            done
        ) &
        CHILD_PID=$!
        trap "kill $CHILD_PID;" SIGTERM SIGINT
        wait $CHILD_PID
    } &
    SUBSHELL_PID=$!
done
```

Comment: Beware that `kill -0 $pid` tells you if there's a process with this PID, it doesn't tell you whether that's the process you mean. I don't advise this in a production program: sooner or later this will lead to your killing an unrelated critical process that's reused the PID.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but that is a very good observation.  Thanks again.